# Match logic between two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists,am trying to find the any element in lista is present in list,I know I can two forloops to do a match
,are there better ways to achieve this without two for loops

```
lista=['LA.BF.2.1']
listb=['LA.BF.2.1','LA.BF64.1.2.1','LA.BF64.1.1']
for element in lista:
    for element in listb:
                  match
```

Comment: @kasra - sorry I dont need intersection logic...its a match logic..updated question

Comment: Still *am trying to find the any element in lista is present in list,* means intersection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using `any`

```
>>> lista=['LA.BF.2.1']
>>> listb=['LA.BF.2.1','LA.BF64.1.2.1','LA.BF64.1.1']
>>> any([ i in listb for i in lista])
True
```

Comment: @nullp - I need to know if there is a match for each i in lista,how to do that?

Comment: for data `lista=['LA.BF.2.1','LA.BF.2.2']
listb=['LA.BF.2.1','LA.BF64.1.2.1','LA.BF64.1.1']` ,I get the output as False,there is a match for LA.BF.2.1

Comment: @PythonProg I think you are looking for `any` then, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to find any element in `lista` that is also present in `listb` , you can convert the lists to set, and then do `set.intersection` .

Example -

```
>>> lista=['LA.BF.2.1','SOMETHINGELSE']
>>> listb=['LA.BF.2.1','LA.BF64.1.2.1','LA.BF64.1.1']
>>>
>>> list(set(lista).intersection(listb))
['LA.BF.2.1']
```

Comment: I want to see if there is a match or not for each element  of lista in listb, either case I need a response of true or false,basically if there is a match or not..

Comment: can you please define match?

Comment: Do you mean if any one element in lista is in listb, then return true, else if all elements in lista are not in listb return false ?